# how do I embed an existing xna 4 app into silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, xna, silverlight-5.0

I've been struggling with this for a while, I have an XNA 4 app running just fine and I'd like to embed it into silverlight. I can't find any information on how this could be done (pretty much everything I've googled has been about silverilght 5 beta where silverlight 5 RC has changed code and stuff).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight 5 supports limited subset of XNA and cannot execute existing XNA apps as is. You would have to port your application to Silverlight 5. Latest silverlight toolkit (Sep. 2011) provides templates, samples and integration with XNA [content pipeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/10/04/silverlight-toolkit-september-2011-for-silverlight-5-what-s-new.aspx#chap1) to help you started.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, the current Silverlight implementation of XNA supports only shader model 2.0 It means no more than 64 shader instructions among other limitations.

I understood that we could maybe have shader model 3 while under full trust for the final release but nothing certain here...

But more important is that a SL app is a web delivered app. Therefore you don't want to donwload 200Mb of data before being able to play a SL game. Streaming of game resourcesis mandatory... and requires architectural modifications.